# Los cambios que realizo en mi repositorio local no se actualizan en GitHub

Tags: git, github

Lo que sucede es que estoy iniciando con todo este tema de `Git`. Creé mi carpeta local en mi `PC`, puse los archivos y logré configurar con `GitHub`.

Lo que sucede es que cuando hago un cambio localmente no se actualiza en `GitHub`

Comment: Hola, @JuanFelipeRubioTapias, te sugiero que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En cuanto a tu duda, te respondo, si usas [git](https://git-scm.com/), entonces debes empezar con un tutorial que te explique lo que es un `commit` y un `fork` y otra cantidad de cosas esenciales para el uso de un sistema de versiones. Solo te puedo decir que cada vez que modifiques archivos en tu carpeta local, debes realizar un `add`, un `commit` y luego un `push`, ojo, esto es a grosso modo. Lo mejor es que busques más información al respecto. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

### Importante

No olvidar establecer los datos personales mediante:

```
git config --global user.name "Tu nombre"
git config --global user.email "tu-correo@dominio.com"
```

Si es la primera vez que utilizas `git` en tu máquina

---

Para que puedan reflejarse en GitHub debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Descripción de lo que has hecho"
```

Y por último, hacer un PUSH

```
git push origin master # Si estás utilizando la rama master
```

Si has realizado los pasos anteriormente descrito y no te funciona, debes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Una vez definido tu proyecto en GitHub, deberás:

   - Ingresar al directorio de trabajo de tu máquina local: `cd proyecto`
   - Una vez allí debes escribir:

     ```
     git init
     git remote add origin https://github.com/tu-usuario/tuproyecto.git
     git add .
     git commit -m "Commit inicial"
     ```